# PowerShell, Calling a function from a other PS Script and returning a Object

Tags: powershell, object, pipeline

How it is possible to call a function from a other PowerShell script an returning the object?

Main Script:

```
# Run function script
. C:\MySystem\Functions.ps1

RunIE

$ie.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com")  
# The Object $ie is not existing
```

Functions Script:

```
function RunIE($ie) 
{
$ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just "output" the object from the function like so:

```
function RunIE
{ 
    $ie = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application 
    Write-Output $ie
}
```

or more idiomatically

```
function RunIE 
{ 
    New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application 
}
```

Then assign the output to a variable in your main script:

```
$ie = RunIE
```

Comment: To complete the answer, you might add `. RunIE` :)

Comment: I assumed that `. C:\MySystem\Functions.ps1` already dot sourced the RunIE function.  In that case, `$ie = RunIE` is sufficient.

Comment: I meant "you might add also note that `. RunIE` is possible. I was talking about the original example where the function looked like `function RunIE { $ie = .. }`.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. That does seem kind of gross though - promoting function scope variables to the current scope that way?  :-)

Comment: I don't say it is the best solution. I'll just add my comment so that I'm satisfied and you don't have to edit your answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Keith provided *the* answer that is the best solution for your problem. Anyway, I'd like to add something to have the answer more complete.

If your function is defined like this:

```
function getvars
{
    $a = 10
    $b = "b"
}
```

then it just creates new variable in scope of function `RunIE` and assigns something in it. After the function completes, the `$ie` variable is discarded.

In some cases (I use it for some type of debugging), you might need to execute function in the current scope and that is known as `dot sourcing'. Just try Google and you will see.

```
PS> $a = 11
PS> getvars
PS> $a, $b
11

PS> $a = 11
PS> . getvars
PS> $a, $b
10
b
```